# How can I create a fixed size in the graphics of ggplot despite variable name length?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need the *graphics* of the plots I create to have the same width while keeping the text areas on the left side dynamic: when I export the plots below to ie sizes 200 x 400 (HxW), the width of the graphics depend on the lengths of the variable names:

[image: Example one]

[image: Example two]

Is there a way to keep the width of the graphics fixed, ie at 400, and allow a dynamic variation in the text instead? I managed to match the widths of the graphics below, by measuring the widths on the screen with a ruler which is not an optimal solution when you want to match many plots.

[image: Example 3]
[image: Example 4]

*(The plots need to be aligned to the right for the graphics to match, I can't see if that is possible, feel free to edit if you know how)*

Code:

```
set.seed(10)
Varnames <- c("One name", "A very very long name of a variable", "Another variable name")  # Variable names to be changed here
Varvalues <- runif(3, 0, 5)          # Odds ratios
spread <- runif(3, 0, 2)             # Confidence intervals
CI_hi <- Varvalues + spread/2        # Upper level of CIs
CI_lo <- Varvalues - spread/2        # Lower level of CIs

library(ggplot2)
vertline <- c(1)                     # preparing vertical lines to be shown in graph
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=Varvalues, y=Varnames)) +
  geom_point(shape=18, color="deepskyblue3", size=3) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = vertline,
             size=0.1
  ) +
  geom_errorbarh(
    aes(xmin=CI_lo, xmax=CI_hi),
    size=.6,
    height=0.3,
    colour="deepskyblue3",
    linetype="solid"
  ) +
  scale_x_log10(
    breaks = c(0.2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),
    labels = c("0.2", "1", "2", "", "","5","","","","", "10", "","","","","15"),
    limits = c(0.2,15)
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', colour = "grey"),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    text=element_text(family="Georgia", size=14)
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one option would be to set a fix letters amount for every graphic (e.g. 50), that defines a "length", then complete every string with leading spaces to achieve this length.
This way, every string has the same "length", and the space width will remain the same no matter the text.

```r
Varnames <- c("One name", "A very very long name of a variable", "Another variable name")  # Variable names to be changed here
Varnames <- stringr::str_pad(Varnames, width = 50, side = "left", pad = " ")

# [1] "                                          One name"
# [2] "               A very very long name of a variable"
# [3] "                             Another variable name"
```

Comment: Not a bad idea actually. Will have this as an alternative approach until further notice :-) thx

Comment: Ok so I tried this out of curiosity, and unfortunately it doesn't work as good as expected; long variables still tend to squish the graphics to the right for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems come from the fact that, 2 strings with same number of letters will not necessarely have the same graphic length....  
e.g. iiiiiiiiii and wwwwwwwwww :-)

Comment: a very, very ugly way can be to access to the computed graphic lengths through `ggplot_build`, then completing the variable names with the above method to achieve the desired graphic length... But does it worth ? Up to you :)

Comment: I tried this option and changed the font to Courier New on the y axis to have the same spacing throughout all letters and it actually worked but it doesn't look as desired :-( anyway it could be a solution, I guess.